# Livecycle designer render a blank page if the form ends with odd pages

Tags: javascript, designer, livecycle

i am designing a form in Livecycle es4 designer, the form is saved as .xdp and we have a .xml as input, based on the data stream the form extends to n number of pages, i need to end my form on an even page always,
if there are 3 pages based on the data, i need to show an blank page as the  4th page. if there are 4 pages based on data stream we need not show the extra blank page.

i have added a blank page in my designer made it hidden from layout, , wrapped in a sub form  and in the layout editor :ready i have written the following script

```
var pageCount = xfa.layout.pageCount();
if(pageCount%2==0){Blank.presence = "hidden";}
{Blank.presence = "visible";}
```

but my form now which is 3 pages does not append the blank page, any direction will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance
CW

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **layout:ready** event fires every time the form changes. For example:
initialy 3 pages -> script adds one more -> form changed -> script fires again and removes 4th page...

Secondly, is the **Blank**(empty page) visible or hidden from the start? Depending on that the Blank will be included or not in the page count at the first script run.

You could set Blank as visible from the start and per script remove it if the condition is true. You won't need else-part in this case.